# Angularjs display message with /n

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to get angularjs to read my new lines properly, in this case /n is a new line.

here is my acual response from my variable `message` with the info i would like to display:

```
jeg\n\nlurer\npaa hva
```

when i display the variable in the view with `{{ message }}`i get:

```
Jeg lurer paa hva
```

while it really should be:

```
Jeg

lurer
paa hva
```

how can i make angular read the /n as new line?

Comment: if you are showing this info on the front-end with html you can try using <br /> as option for new line.

Comment: @user1952854 how may i change the creating of the default /n to br?

Comment: @maria `description.replace(/\\n/g, '<br>')`

Answer (score 2):

Use some css styling

```
  <div class="pre-line">{{message}}</div>
```

n in CSS

```
 div.pre-line {
      white-space: pre-line;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Put your `{{message}}` inside a `<pre>` tag like,

`<pre>{{message}}</pre>`

which will take care of the link breaks.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `ng-bind-html`?

Comment: Yes, using <pre> or change to </br> is a right answer, not this ^^

Answer (score 0):

Adding `<pre>` tag around of your `{{ message }}` will resolve your problem.
You can add this feature of the pre tag with css.